# Tokenize and apply command

Tags: token-lists

I have a string separated with commas. On that I want to get each element and apply a command. I have the following, which works.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[trim]{tokenizer}

\newcommand{\cadd}[1]{
        \def\Source{#1}
    \whiledo{\not\equal{\Source}{}}
    {
        \GetTokens{TokenOne}{TokenTwo}{\Source}
        \textbf{\TokenOne}
        \let\Source\TokenTwo
    }
}

\begin{document}

\cadd{a,b,c}

\end{document}
```

But I would like to have the following

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[trim]{tokenizer}

\newcommand{\cadd}[1]{
    \whiledo{\not\equal{#1}{}}
    {
        \GetTokens{TokenOne}{TokenTwo}{#1}
        \textbf{\TokenOne}
        \let\#1\TokenTwo
    }
}

\begin{document}

\cadd{a,b,c}

\end{document}
```

But the `\let\#1\TokenTwo` is giving an error. How can I use `#1` with `\let`

Comment: Why? Is it because it seems cleaner as opposed to using an intermediate macro `\Source`? You could also process this list using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and not have to worry about re-assigning something to `#1`.

Comment: @Werner I tried a quick demo with `etoolbox`, but it does not strip _trailing_ spaces from each entry. Thus the output is slightly different from the one which seems to be required from the example given.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`#1` gets replaced at the first call of the macro. If macro `\cadd`

```
\newcommand{\cadd}[1]{
    \whiledo{\not\equal{#1}{}}
    {
        \GetTokens{TokenOne}{TokenTwo}{#1}
        \textbf{\TokenOne}
        \let\#1\TokenTwo
    }
}
```

is called as `\cadd{a,b,c}`, then it becomes to:

```
<space>
\whiledo{\not\equal{a,b,c}{}}<space>
{<space>
  \GetTokens{TokenOne}{TokenTwo}{a,b,c}<space>
  \textbf{\TokenOne}<space>
  \let\#1\TokenTwo
}<space>
```

- The line `\let\#1\TokenTwo` consists of the `\let` assignment `\let\#=1` and `\TokenTwo`.
  `#1` is only replaced in macro expansion with the first argument.
- There are lots of space tokens (caused by the end of line):

  - The first is ignored in vertical mode, because the paragraph has not yet started.
  - The second is ignored, if `\whiledo` reads the loop body as undelimited argument.
  - The third and fourth will be present in the output.
  - The last is removed because of the end of paragraph.

  Space tokens at the line end can be avoided by using the comment char, as seen
  in the following example.

There are many parsers for comma separated lists. One of them is provided by package `kvsetkeys`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{kvsetkeys}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cadd}[1]{%
  \comma@parse{#1}{\caddentry}%
}
\newcommand*{\caddentry}[1]{%
  \textbf{[#1]}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cadd{a,b,c}

\cadd{ a , b , c }

\cadd{abc, def, ghi}

\cadd{{ with spaces }, {a b c}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you very much! Vote +1.

Answer (score 5):

Heiko has covered the detail here nicely. For completeness, a solution using the LaTeX3 comma-list mapping function `\clist_map_inline:nn`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \cadd } { m }
  { \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} { [ \textbf {##1} ] } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\cadd{a,b,c}

\cadd{ a , b , c }

\cadd{abc, def, ghi}

\cadd{{ with spaces }, {a b c}}

\end{document}
```

The underlying idea is much the same as Heiko's answer: rather than have to do the mapping by hand, use a pre-built command that deals with finding the end of the list.

Comment: Also works very nicely. Thanks! Vote +1.